# Removing wrapper div without Jquery (raw javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, wrapper

I know there is a solution with Jquery called unwrap, but I am writing "raw" JavaScript.
I didn't find any solution without jQuery.

I'd like to remove a div like so:

```
<div><div id="mydiv">Important text here</div></div>
```

After removal of "mydiv":

```
<div>Important text here</div>
```

What should I do, I'd like to know the theory.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try browsing jQuery's source?

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer, yes, but I couldn't really figure it out, I am not a really jQuery junkie.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

shouldn't this line work

```
 document.getElementById("mydiv").outerHTML = document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML
```

See this [JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/oxapac/edit#javascript,html) (inspect the element)

Comment: Thanks it worked! Now i'll read more about this mysterious "outerHTML" property.

Comment: Best solution, because it keeps the position in DOM tree!

Comment: I'm finding the events attached to elements in the innerHtml get lost. Is there a trick to keep those?

Comment: This worked for me for my custom web-component.  It allowed me to remove <my-custom-tag></ my-custom-tag> around the elements I want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.removeChild) method for that:

```
var divToRemove = document.getElementById('mydiv').;
var tmpStr = divToRemove.innerHTML;
var parent = divToRemove.parentNode;
parent.removeChild(divToRemove);
parent.inerHTML(tmpStr);
```

Comment: This will completely rewrite the parent innerHTML which isn't good. (I may have more text in-between)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
​var el = document.getElementById('mydiv');
var text = el.innerText; //or el.innerHTML
    el.parentNode.innerHTML = text;
​
```

This would replace the html of mydiv's parent with the content of mydiv.

Comment: Same problem like @antyrat's answer.

Comment: So will using outerHTML, but this isn't cross browser compatible. http://jsfiddle.net/gRoberts/ksCbT/ shows it working.

Comment: I tested my code and it worked in: firefox chrome safari opera and internet explorer.